# Using PHP Session variables to send email form

Tags: php, email, variables, session, session-variables

I am currently trying to use the same php session variables saved in the DB to fill in information for an email form. Unfortunately as far as i can see the code is correct but the email won't return errors or refuses to send.

```
var_dump ($_POST); 
if 
(isset($_POST['submit']));
    $to = "brendonexus@gmail.com"; // this is your Email address
    $from = $_SESSION['email']; // this is the sender's Email address
    $fullname = $_SESSION['fullname'];
    $subject = "ICE Live Streaming Event - Online questions";
    $subject2 = "Copy of the questions you submitted.";
    $message = $fullname . " asked the following:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];
    $message2 = "Thank you, your question has been received and will be put forward to the panel for consideration." . $first_name . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];
    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    $headers2 = "From:" . $to;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers); // this is the message that is sent
    mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2); // sends a copy of the message to the sender
    echo "Mail Sent. Thank you " . $fullname . ", We have recieved your email.";
    // You can also use header('Location: thank_you.php'); to redirect to another page.
```

Edit: I have managed to get it to send an email now but it seems that when i var_dump the session variables the only one that returns is the username. Whats confusing is that if the username works and all the other code is built the same then i do not understand why there is a compatibility issue.

Comment: where is `session_start()` in this file??

Comment: That is right at the top, I can assure you it's there :)

Comment: can u print all session values and check is session is set properly or not??

Comment: Yes i can, i have also pasted the variables in my original question

Comment: Can you try to catch the Mail exception (if any)?

`if (!mail(...)) {
   echo "error";
}`

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're asking, I am new to this :(

Comment: Can you confirm that you're able to manually invoke `mail()` to send an email?

Comment: Why not you replace the mail function with phpmailer...

Also could you echo $from to see that it is ok?

And the code looks very wrong, why mixing $_POST and $_SESSION for 'email', 'fullname'

Comment: I have managed to get the code to send an email but some of the $_SESSION variables are not carrying information, the only one that carries information now is the username. They have all been built the same way so i do not understand why the rest of the $_SESSION variables will not function the same.